# React Ant Design Modal Method update on state change

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router, antd

I'm currently migrating to `antd`, and have a modal appear on a certain route (ie /userid/info). I'm able to achieve this if I use the antd `Modal` react component, but I'd like to be able to use the modal methods provided such as `Modal.confirm`,`Modal.info` and `Modal.error` as they offer nicer ui straight out of the box.

I'm running to multiple issues such as having the modal rendered multiple times (both initially and after pressing delete in the delete user case), and unable to make it change due to state (ie display loading bar until data arrives). This is what i've tried but it constantly renders new modals, ive tried something else but that never changed out of displaying `<Loader />` even though `isFetching` was false. I'm not sure what else to try.

```
const UserInfoFC: React.FC<Props> = (props) => {

  const user = props.user.id;

  const [isFetching, setIsFetching] = React.useState<boolean>(true);
  const [userInfo, setUserInfo] = React.useState<string>('');

  const modal = Modal.info({
    content: <Loader />,
    title: 'User Info',
  });

  const displayModal = () => {

    const renderInfo = (
      <React.Fragment>
        <p>display user.info</p>
      </React.Fragment>
    );

    const fetchInfo = async () => {
      try {
        user = // some api calls
        setUserInfo(user.info);
        modal.update({ content: renderInfo })
      } catch (error) {
        // todo
      }
      setIsFetching(false);
    };
    fetchInfo();
  };

  displayModal();

  return(<div />);
};
```

reference: https://ant.design/components/modal/#components-modal-demo-confirm

edit: here is a replication of one of the issues I face: https://codesandbox.io/embed/antd-reproduction-template-1jsy8

Comment: What are you trying to do in `displayModal`? you not rendering anything like so. Also you should provide a producible example, refer to [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @DennisVash ive updated my post with a codesandbox link. Ideally there would be a react component instead of having to use these methods but I dont see it in the docs if there is

Comment: What do you mean by "nicer UI?" There's no real discernible difference between the modal created by the React component and the methods in AntD.  You can accomplish the same thing much more easily by simply using the component version.  This seems like an unnecessary complication.  If you have problems using the component I'm happy to help.

Comment: @RutherfordWonkington the methods are essentially a template. They contain no borders for the header and footer and already contain a relevant icon. A clear example is the  [internationalization](https://ant.design/components/modal/#components-modal-demo-locale) one where there are two modals but the ui is clearly different. You can also see this in the example in the link i provided in the post as opposed to the basic example at the top of that page.

Comment: Oh I see.  You can definitely recreate that fairly simply, but if you want to use the method, I'd try placing it in an empty ```useEffect``` hook so it only runs one time when the component mounts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of going to /:id/info and routing to a component which would have returned an empty div but displayed a modal, I created a displayInfo component that displays a button and that controls the modal. I got rid of attempting to use routes for this.

What I have now is similar to the [docs](https://ant.design/components/modal/#components-modal-demo-info)

Comment: Sounds like it probably makes more sense than using a separate route just to display a notification.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my comment, you can use a `useEffect` hook with an empty dependency array to run a function once when the component mounts. You can initiate an async call, wait for it to resolve and store the data in your state, and launch a modal with a second hook once the data arrives.

I made a sandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/withered-thunder-p8btv)

Comment: I'd like to change the contents of the modal (ie have the spinner inside it while loading and then populate with data) instead of have the spinner outside it. I tried this based on your sandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-snyder-otebd) but it ends up rendering multiple modals

Comment: That complicates things. Another drawback of using these methods is that you cannot pass props to them, you initialize them **once** with content and other props that do not change.  So I'm sorry to say you're probably out of luck, unless you close and re-open the modal when the content arrives, which is not great UX.  As I mentioned before, dealing with the components is much, much more flexible.